# Combining jQuery UI Tabs and jScrollPane fails

Tags: jquery-ui, jscrollpane, jquery-tabs

I have problem getting newer version of [jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to work with jQuery UI tabs.
I get only one tab (first one) working, but no others; i tried fix explained here with previous version, placing additional `<div>` controlled by tabs (and inside are divs controlled by jScrollPane) , as described [here](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/tabs_example.html),   but still with no luck. Has anyone experienced simmilar issues ? Thanks for clues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to solution at last more/less on my own, of course with help by looking at [this explanation](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/tabs_example.html) given by jscrollpane author himself about this issue, but for previous version of jscrollpane.

As this did not work out of the box, and i still had problems implementing the solution, i added a click listener to tabs links, and when clicked, added jscrollpane to content div, like this

```
jQuery("#tabs ul li a").click(function () {
clickednum = "#tabs-" + jQuery(this).parent().attr("id");
jQuery(clickednum + " .skroler").jScrollPane();
    });
```

what i am doing here, is to wait for user to click on some tab link, and then add jScrollPane to tab content that coresponds to clicked tab link.

**.skroler** is an extra-div where is tab content, because it is described by script author that it must be done this way in order to work)

I am reckognizing tabs by **li** id attribute (which i was in need to generate from PHP. for other reasons)

This is specific implementation - from working example, probably it could be done simpler in other environment.

Ah, and of course, at the start of the story,  you need to initialize jScrollPane to first opened tab like

```
jQuery("#tabs-1 .skroler").jScrollPane();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and solved it by adding ids to the li tags that correspond to the generated tabs:

```
<ul>
      <li id="details"><a href="#tabs-1">Details</a></li>
      <li id="history"><a href="#tabs-2">History</a></li>
      <li id="examinations"><a href="#tabs-3">Examinations</a></li>
      <li id="diagnosis"><a href="#tabs-4">Diagnosis</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then, for example:

```
$('#diagnosis').click(function() {  
    $('.diagnosis').jScrollPane();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    //for the initially loaded tab
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.panel).jScrollPane();
    },
    //for the tabs opened later
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.newPanel).jScrollPane();
    },
});
```

More info here http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/